# Uber universal link ending in endless loop

Tags: uber-api

I'm trying to use an Uber universal link on iOS. Following the affiliate program page documentation ([here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/affiliate-program/introduction)), I'm using a link like this: `https://m.uber.com/ul/?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>`.

When I use a dummy client id (or don't put one at all) and open it in Safari, the link prompts me to open the App Store.

When I put my actual client id, I end up in an infinite redirect loop between `uber.com` and `launch1.co`.

Should I do something to enable this feature for my client id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: this is a bug, it will be fixed.

Comment: I'm not seeing the top right "uber.com" link on iOS. I'm also seeing the same behaviour where Safari is stuck in an endless redirect loop. But anyways, I'm not tied to using that kind of link. I just want a link that will open in the app store if the user doesn't have the app and open the app if they do, all while recording my referral code. What should I use?

Comment: @agregoire - apologize for confusion got confirmation now - it is a bug and will be fixed. No specific timeframe when this will be done.

Comment: The issue should be resolved now, thank you for the report! Let us know if you are still seeing issues though.